# Bash AutoStart script does not copy files from shared folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi

I have added a startup bash script to a device running Raspbian (Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).

This is my script:

**SysmacApp.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d /home/pi/App ]; then
  mkdir -p /home/pi/App;
fi

if [ ! -d /home/pi/Shared/Service ]; then
  mkdir -p /home/pi/Shared/Service;
fi

if [ ! -d /home/pi/Shared/Service/Data ]; then
  mkdir -p /home/pi/Shared/Service/Data;
fi

if [ ! -d /home/pi/Shared/Sysmac ]; then
  mkdir -p /home/pi/Shared/Sysmac;
fi

sudo mount -t cifs //10.10.0.1/SysmacApp /home/pi/App -o username=*****,password=*****
cp /home/pi/App/Service/* /home/pi/Shared/Service -r
cp /home/pi/App/Sysmac/* /home/pi/Shared/Sysmac -r
cp /home/pi/App/Shared/* /home/pi/Shared  
sudo umount /home/pi/App

cd /home/pi/Shared/Service
dotnet ./SysmacService.dll &
sleep 2
cd /home/pi/Shared/Sysmac
dotnet ./SysmacUI.Skia.Gtk.dll &
```

So basically:

- Create some directories if not exists.
- Copy two applications from a shared folder.
- Execute these 2 applications.

The script is executed because the apps run after a reboot, but the information is not copied unless I manually execute this script in a terminal.

To run the script I have added an entry to the `/etc/xdg/autostart` folder:

**SysmacApp.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=SysmacApp
Comment=Starts sysmac application
Exec=/home/pi/Shared/SysmacApp.sh
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

If I remotely reboot the device the applications are executed but not copied from the shared folder.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No logs to check ?

Comment: I'm not a Linux user, let me see if I can find something. @Itération122442

Comment: You can redirect output of the script like so: `Exec=/home/pi/Shared/SysmacApp.sh > /some/file/somewhere` and check the content of the output file.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: What's the point in testing the directory for existence, before doing a `mkdir -p`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to debug it, so I suggest you to update your script as follow:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function run {
    if [ ! -d /home/pi/App ]; then
      mkdir -p /home/pi/App;
    fi

    if [ ! -d /home/pi/Shared/Service ]; then
      mkdir -p /home/pi/Shared/Service;
    fi

    if [ ! -d /home/pi/Shared/Service/Data ]; then
      mkdir -p /home/pi/Shared/Service/Data;
    fi

    if [ ! -d /home/pi/Shared/Sysmac ]; then
      mkdir -p /home/pi/Shared/Sysmac;
    fi

    sudo mount -t cifs //10.10.0.1/SysmacApp /home/pi/App -o username=*****,password=*****
    cp /home/pi/App/Service/* /home/pi/Shared/Service -r
    cp /home/pi/App/Sysmac/* /home/pi/Shared/Sysmac -r
    cp /home/pi/App/Shared/* /home/pi/Shared  
    sudo umount /home/pi/App

    cd /home/pi/Shared/Service
    dotnet ./SysmacService.dll &
    sleep 2
    cd /home/pi/Shared/Sysmac
    dotnet ./SysmacUI.Skia.Gtk.dll &
}

run 2>&1 1>/var/log/myscript.log
```

Then, after a reboot, check the file `/var/log/myscript.log` for some issue.

Comment: `./SysmacApp.sh: line 42: /var/log/sysmacapp.log: Permission denied` I've tried by adding sudo run....

Comment: If I try to save log file in /home/pi/Shared folder: `./SysmacApp.sh: line 42: run: command not found`

Comment: You can write log to `/tmp` too if you want.